# Determinants of smart contract execution fee

Tags: token, ethereum, fee

Is it possible to decompose in details how much an additional line of code will impact the gas price for execution, i.e. transferring a token from one wallet to another, before deploying a smart contract?

Test networks are not very accurate there…

Answer (score 0):

I think not. The final gas price is a dynamic variable. It depends on many other dynamic variables that cannot be computed beforehand because the actions these variables encode will happen in the future. Of course you can get an approximation based on the current gas price.

Comment: But white the assembly code it should be possible to calculate that…?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to decompose in details how much an additional line of code will impact the gas price for execution, i.e. transferring a token from one
> wallet to another, before deploying a smart contract?

Yes.

You can disassemble the compiled bytecode and then calculate the gas manually from the EVM instructions based on the [Ethereum yellow paper](https://github.com/ethereum/yellowpaper).

Comment: Thanks for that answer. I will try that - that’s what I thought already.

Comment: You can also use tools like Brownie to show the gas cost for you as the part of unit tests https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/core-transactions.html

Comment: Ok sounds great. Would it be possible to have a kind of personal discussion with you on that topic? Do you offer any kind of consulting here?

Comment: Please use Brownie Discord for any community support.